# Swift Create local notification for every x day

Tags: swift, nsdate, uilocalnotification, nsdatecomponents

I have found many answers in objective C, but I am looking for a way to create a local notification for every Monday and Tuesday, or every Saturday and Thursday etc etc. In my code I have created a few NSDateComponents

```
let date2 = NSDateComponents()
    date2.hour = 4
    date2.minute = 3


    let date3 = NSDateComponents()
    date3.hour = 12
    date3.minute = 33
```

...

and then put them into an array

```
datesArray = [date2, date3]
```

I have found very little resources on how to create local notifications in swift 2 and all i have been able to do so far is create a local notification 10 seconds from when I build and run the application, but this has no connection to the dates i created.

```
    var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10)
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day
    localNotification.alertBody = "Take Out Track"
    localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

What I am trying to do is create a notification for each date in the array, and then have the ability to say only repeat that on Monday Wednesday and Saturday or whatever the user selects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have to use nscalender through which you can get the weekday like in iOS weekday for sunday is 1 , Monday is 2 and so on.... through that you can set on which day you have to fire your notification.
and also check out that tuturiol

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-event-kit-programming-tutorial/